# PhysX overlap always returns false

Tags: physx

I am creating a game using PhysX as the physics engine and I have a function which checks the overlapped bodies based on a sphere geometry. When there are overlapping bodies I just set a force on them. The problem is that the overlap function always return false. No matter what I feed it with. Here is my code:

```
void PhysxManager::ExplosionSphere(const glm::vec3& pos, float radius, float _force)
{
    PxOverlapBuffer hit;            // [out] Overlap results
    PxSphereGeometry overlapShape = PxSphereGeometry(radius);  // [in] shape to test for overlaps
    PxTransform shapePose = PxTransform(PxVec3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));    // [in] initial shape pose (at distance=0)

    if (mScene->overlap(overlapShape, shapePose, hit, PxSceneQueryFilterData(PxQueryFlag::eNO_BLOCK))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < hit.nbTouches; ++i) {
            auto actor = dynamic_cast<physx::PxRigidDynamic*>(hit.touches[i].actor);
            if (actor) {
                PxVec3 force = (actor->getGlobalPose().p - PxVec3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z));

                actor->addForce(force * _force);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might be the problem or maybe an alternative to overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work as mentioned above. Instead I made it to work as I wanted using

> PxSceneQueryExt::overlapMultiple

This was suggested by NVidia on their forums as an alternative. Note that I wanted to work with multiple objects in the query.

I used it like this :

```
PxSphereGeometry overlapShape = PxSphereGeometry(radius);  // [in] shape to test for overlaps
PxTransform shapePose = PxTransform(PxVec3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z), PxQuat(physx::PxHalfPi, physx::PxVec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));    // [in] initial shape pose (at distance=0)

std::unique_ptr<PxOverlapHit[]> hitOv = std::make_unique<PxOverlapHit[]>(4096);
int howMany = PxSceneQueryExt::overlapMultiple(*mScene, overlapShape, shapePose, hitOv.get(), 4096, PxQueryFilterData(PxQueryFlag::eSTATIC | PxQueryFlag::eDYNAMIC | PxQueryFlag::eNO_BLOCK));
```